# Server Location (Catalina Home) folder is not valid

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, netbeans-8

Trying to create Web application based on Tomcat. Can't set Tomcat folder:
[image]

Error:

```
The specified Server Location (Catalina Home) folder is not valid.
```

[image]

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 15):

Netbeans 8.1 doesn't support Tomcat 9.

Upgrade your Netbeans to 8.2, or use Tomcat 8 instead.

Comment: So, how does this answer help someone who already has Netbeans 8.2?

Comment: @GOKUL KANNAMBALLY BALACHNADRAN answer worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

Download Tomcat (Windows Service Installer) format, then Install

Go to Installation Folder, then Try to open Tomcat 9.0 folder, then
Windows Message Asked, then Take permission to open folder

That All and my purpose was solved to install Tomcat 9.0 in Netbeans 11.3

Answer (score 7):

Sometime you have to open the folder of tomcat server after installing it. It wants permission to open it.then
Your problem of catlina home will be solved...

Comment: Specially when you are using Windows 10.

Comment: And Windows 11!

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the environment variables:

```
PATH: ......C:\Progra..\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.52-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.52\bin
CATALINA_HOME: F:\apache-tomcat-7.0.52-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.52
JAVA_HOME: C:\Progra..\Java\jdk1.7.0_51
JRE_HOME: C:\Progra..\Java\jre7
```

and restart apache after it!

Answer (score 1):

Open the folder and then you find the single folder with apache tomcat 9.0. Press open then, before you just selected the main folder didn't opened it.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

## Check Permissions

One possible reason that someone might receive this error, especially on MacOS or *nix platforms, is **permissions**. On MacOS, the NetBeans 8-ish installers will install Tomcat in the NetBeans Applications folder, e.g., `/Applications/NetBeans/apache-tomcat-maj.min.patch`.

If you are following that pattern and upgrade Tomcat to a currently compatible version with your version of NetBeans, you may be forced to unpack the binary as `sudo`, e.g., `sudo tar xvf ~/Downloads/apache-tomcat-maj.min.patch.tar.gz -C /Applications/NetBeans`. This will untar your NetBeans install without write permissions for `group, other`, e.g., `0755` or `drwxr-xr-x ...`.

You can correct that with `sudo chown -R user:group apache-tomcat-maj.min.patch` as apropos, `sudo chown -R javafueled:admin apache-tomcat-maj.min.patch`

Answer (score 0):

To solve this in **(Netbeans 8.2)**, just add the directory of the Apache Tomcat server (where you unzipped your Tomcat server to)

[image]

The directory you see in Catalina Home in the picture is where I unzipped Tomcat to.

Set is also in System Environment:

[image]

**Do not add a semicolon at the end**

Answer (score 0):

Just download the appropriate tomcat file and unzip.[image]

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, if you've just installed Tomcat, by default the permissions of CATALINA_HOME will be locked down.  To correct this issue, just browse to the tomcat directory (by default C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat x.x) and open it.  Windows will prompt you with a security warning and once you've accepted the warning, you can complete adding the server to NetBeans (You may have to re-browse to the directory to refresh the NetBeans UI).

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same Issue, Sometime you have to open the folder of tomcat server after installing it. Open it through the Windows Explorer in windows, Since It wants Admin permission to open it. Then you might need to restart your computer

Then Your problem of catlina home will be solved while creating the Server Instance through Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check 2 things.And those are-

1. Check whether the java version that you have installed in your pc is compatiable with the tomcat version or not.
2. Check the compatability between your netbeans version and tomcat version.
   And you will find the compatability info in [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)