# Problem when adding tomcat server to Netbeans

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vHSd.png)

I've installed tomcat 9.0.27 in the path C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.27. I also have Netbeans. But when I add the tomcat server this message shows up:
*The specified Server Location (Catalina Home) folder is not valid*

Truth is, I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Greetings @DiegoReal. This is an english only community, for a spanish one visit es.stackoverflow.com. I've edited your question, translated it to english. If you don't know english you should post it at the spanish site. Cheers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Server Location (Catalina Home) folder is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37807636/server-location-catalina-home-folder-is-not-valid)

Comment: If you are using NetBeans 8.1 or earlier then you cannot use Tomcat 9.0.27, so either install Tomcat 8.5 instead, or upgrade to NetBeans 8.2 or later.